I am facing a problem to verify element visibility if element in visible or not using cypress
When I try
cy.get('div.userId')

I want to add condition div.userId is exists/not in dom.
I am expecting not to fail test before checking existence of element in dom.
Like sometimes div.userId is not visible and cy.get(div.userId) fails but we ma need to click another element to make it visible. simple wanna use if-else statement upon this...

@MadhuriVarada is correct, but the other answer is misleading you. It is possible and often required to test for an element that exists or not.
You can easily do it with cypress-if plugin commands

Easy conditional if-else logic for your Cypress tests

Please review the videos and blogs in the above link for better information, especially the Cypress Flakiness Example
  cy.get('[data-cy=customer-item]')
    // the elements are there, the list will not change
    // thus we can set the timeout to 0
    // to quickly move to the next steps
    .not('[data-status=active]', { timeout: 0 })
    .if('exists')
    .sample()
    .click()
    .then(() => {
      // find the button that contains the text "Activate Subscription"
      // and click on it
      cy.contains('Activate Subscription').click()
      // the page should contain a visible element
      // with text "Subscription was activated"
      cy.contains('Subscription was activated').should('be.visible')
    })
    .else('Could not find inactive subscription')

This way you avoid using jQuery expressions that could end up as flaky test, since jQuery does not wait for asynchronous loaded elements.

How is the answer I gave misleading? Where in my answer did I say it was not possible? I pointed out that testing with an if/else is not recommended by Cypress, and to take a closer look at what you're testing before defaulting to using an if/else statement.

cy.get('div.userId').if('visible').click()/trigger('mouseover).else().log('there is no userid in the dom element') 

you have to  install the if else plugin

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Cypress does not recommend you write conditional tests like this. It would be preferable to write your tests to behave in a definite manner and control the application state so that you don't have to deal with if/else. Before implementing something like the below, consider how you could make your test more determinant (mocking application data, for example.)
You can search for a parent element to the div.userId, and then use JQuery functions (which do not have implicit assertions) to check if the div.userId exists.
cy.get('parentElement')
  .then(($el) => {
    if ($el.find('div.userId').length > 0) {
      // code for if the element exists
    } else {
      // code for if the element does not exist
    }
  });


This explanation and solution sounds good to me
